# Rewrite permalink with PHP processing

Tags: permalinks, filters, request-filter

I am creating an unusual URL format for permalinks. I don't think the permalinks can be processed thru mod rewrite, so I need PHP to rewrite the URL somehow.

I was able to create a URL like this:

site.com/2s

This references post ID 100

I would like the user to go to that URL and see the site.com/?p=100 post

How do I setup my plugin to do the following?

```
// receive the url from the address bar
// process the url (find the correct id based on the url)
// show the correct post
```

If you're wondering how I'm processing the link, all I'm doing right now is

```
$post_id = base_convert($short_url_path,36,10);
```

Comment: Note that WP rewrites and mod rewrite are two separate systems that are unconnected to eachother. One uses HTAccess files and is an Apache feature. The other is the pretty permalink system in WordPress

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell ! Would one of these rewrite options slow me to access the correct posts and solve my problem?

Comment: probably not because your chosen URL is ultra generic and there's no way to know if `/2c` refers to your custom scheme, or a page, you're almost certainly going to run into clashes/conflicts. It would be much easier if you use `/something/2c` instead. Adding constraints will help here enormously, and you're going to need a regex that matches these URLs

Comment: Great! Thank you. Can you tell me how to change something/2s into something/100? @TomJNowell because all I can figure out to do is an Apache style rewrite rule and I don't know how to actually bring the URL in, then convert it and call the right post. If I changed it to something/?shorty=2s for example I would still not know how to have WordPress display the correct post.

Comment: do you know how to write a regex that matches the URLs you want and only the URLs you want? Ignore wether a post exists or not, or the PHP code to process it

Comment: @TomJNowell yes. this is for a plugin for wordpress. If it was just a normal site I was building, I would make an htaccess file that includes 

RewriteRule ^shorty/(.*)$ ./shorty.php?slug=$1

then, I would make shorty.php include

$post_id = base_convert($_GET["slug"],36,10);
include "post.php?p=$post_id";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example there are 4 fundamental steps to take. I've tried to use examples below, and they may not work as is, but they demonstrate the fundamental principles needed:

#### 1. Add a query var `shorty`

This whitelists `shorty` and gives the `2c` from `/shorty/2c` somewhere to be stored

```php
function shorty_query_vars( array $qvars ) : array {
    $qvars[] = 'shorty';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'shorty_query_vars' );
```

#### 2. Add a rewrite rule that maps to the shorty query var for /shorty

This takes the URL and uses a regular expression to map it to an ugly permalink, using the query var we just added.

```php
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'shorty/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?shorty=$matches[1]&p=0', 'top' );
} );
```

#### 3. Use pre_get_posts to process it and rewrite `p`

This checks if the query var we just added has a value, aka when the rewrite rule is used, and modifies the main query to pull in the post we want. This is where `base_convert` is called. The main query is what determines the template, and the posts that WP fetches, so this part is where the most modification will be needed:

```php
function process_shorty_if_set( \WP_Query $query ) : void {
    // don't run on admin, and only on the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // return early if shorty isn't set
    if ( empty( $query->get( 'shorty' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $shorty = $query->get( 'shorty' );
    $post_id = base_convert( $shorty, 36, 10 );
    $query->set( 'p', $post_id );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'process_shorty_if_set' );
```

#### 4. Save Permalinks and Test

After you flush permalinks, by visiting the permalink settings page, test this out by visiting `/shorty/2s`, and it should load post 100 if it exists.

More specifically WP will see that 2s does not match the canonical URL and do a redirect to the canonical permalink for SEO purposes.

You may want to install a rewrite rule testing plugin to verify the rule added in step 2 is working and not overridden by another rule with a higher priority ( this can happen if your rule is super generic ). If your rule works but the wrong post or no posts are found when they should be, then the `pre_get_posts` filter will need modifying.

Comment: I'm grateful! This code is not working. I added a ")" to the "empty" line to fix the PHP error there.  I installed a plugin to show what ID is being displayed.   

.... if i go to  /47, it pulls up post 47
... if i go to /?shorty=1b (which translates to 47) the plugin is saying that it's showing me post 47, but wordpress is actually showing me the index with the list of posts. It doesn't show all posts in this list, it just shows a link to post 47.
... if i go to /shorty/1b I get a wordpress 404 page

Comment: it's highly unlikely what I posted would work out of the box, but it's 90% of the way there and answers all the fundamental questions about how to do it. My answer is more about how you'd do it. I'd consider maybe adjusting the rewrite rule to `'index.php?shorty=$matches[1]&p=1'` so it's aware it's for a single post and not the homepage/archive. A rewrite rule analyser will help identify if the right values are mapped and it has the appropriate priority. Note that if you use a value that maps to a post ID that doesn't exist then yes I would expect a 404

Comment: Changing the rewrite rule fixed it!!

Comment: what was your fix?

Comment: I did just what you said. added "&p=1"